# Error: MigrationProvisioningPermanentException: The name is already being used

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I'm trying a cutover migration to Office 365, where I already have existing users. The migration shows this error for some users:

> Error: MigrationProvisioningPermanentException: The name 'some.one' is already being used.

I don't see that name in any of the existing user account settings or the mailbox settings in the Exchange Online Admin Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message most likely refers to the name of an existing mailbox. This name is not visible through the web UI.

1. [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx) or, if you're using MFA, [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell using multi-factor authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775114(v=exchg.160).aspx).
2. List all existing mailboxes:

   ```
   Get-Mailbox
   ```

   If you have a lot of mailboxes and want to just see the problematic one:

   ```
   Get-Mailbox | Where {$._Name -Match "some.one"}
   ```
3. This should show you the existing mailbox with the conflicting name. Rename it using [`Set-Mailbox`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981(v=exchg.160).aspx):

   ```
   Set-Mailbox some.one -Name SomeOne
   ```
4. Start your existing cutover migration batch again to re-try migrating the failed mailboxes.

Comment: Is not there a syntax error around `Where {$._Name -Match "some.one"}`, I believe it should read `Where {$_.Name -Match "some.one"}`. (too short change for edit).

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be solved by assigning Exchange Online licenses to existing users.

Answer (score 0):

also check the exchange users (not mailboxes)

```
#connect full powershell
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential $user
$msoExchangeURL = “https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/”
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $msoExchangeURL -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection 
Import-PSSession $session


#update username 

get-user *username* | set-user -name *new username*
```